# I want to add one input field in view order details

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

In my woocommerce project I want one input field in view order page,If customer click the view order it will show one text box to add notes,I guess,this values should be store in (wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta) table.Can you help me..I tried something..

```
function add_name_on_field() {
     echo '<form class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><table class="variations"
 cellspacing="0"> <tbody><tr>
              <td class="label"><label for="name">Add notes</label></td>
              <td class="value">
                  <input type="text" name="name-on-tshirt" value="" />  <button type="submit"
 class="">Submit</button</td></tr></tbody></table></form>'; }
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity_html',
 'add_name_on_field' );
```

For storing I tried this..

```
function tshirt_order_meta_handler( $item_id ) {
if( WC()->session->__isset( $cart_item_key.'_name_on_tshirt' ) ) {
    wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "name_on_tshirt", WC()->session->get( $cart_item_key.'_name_on_tshirt') );}}
add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'tshirt_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );
```

Comment: "Name on shirt" seems item-specific. I would suggest [Product Add-ons](http://www.woothemes.com/products/product-add-ons/)

Comment: I already use product better add on in single product page Is it possible to add (http://venkateshtravels.in/aaa.png) view order page also..

Comment: And I tried in core <form name="addpro" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name"jes" value="">
 <input type="hidden" name"jes1" value="<?php echo $item_id;?>">
    <input type="submit" name="addcustomcarts" value="Submit" />
  </form>  <?php 
if(isset($_POST['addcustomcarts']))
{echo $jes1=$_POST['jes'];
echo $jes2=$_POST['jes1']; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert(<?php echo $_POST['jes1'] ;?>);
  in order-details.php but I couldnt alert item id alert shows empty value...

Comment: No one can read that much code in the comments. Try editing your question. Product Add-ons will show the data automatically the custom item meta data in order details. I think it makes more sense to capture this meta data before adding to cart instead of adding an extra step *after* the order is processed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check out: http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

There it states how to proceed doing what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,This article says add extra fields on billing,shipping but I want to add like a new form in view details page there is no submission I can add the field and submit but I want to know how to submit...

Comment: (http://venkateshtravels.in/aaa.png)   <br>.Please see this image and you will know...Here I want to submit..Can you help me..